# child div overlapping rounded (with radius) container when at width of 2%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a long rectangle shape container with a radius.

And I also have 3 child divs, in the container.

Here it is:

[image: normal]

As you can see in the picture above, the first child container (white) and the third (red) have also been set a radius to match to containers radius.

Now, the child containers width will be dynamic (changeable by the user). So the user will be able to change the widths of all three child containers to meet their needs.

But take a look at what happens when I give the third container a width of 2%:

[image: with 2% width]

the same thing happens when i do the same to the first child (it overlaps the containers rounded borders).

Child container 1 (white) is floating to the left and child container 3 (red) is floating to the right.

I need a way to stop the overlapping from happening.

I am able to use JS and JQuery incase your wondering.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
CSS:

```
.parent {
    border: 1px solid #5B5B5B;
    height: 30px;
    width: 80%;
    right: 0%;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    <? set_radius("25px",true);
    set_box_shadow("1px","1px","#F8F8F8");?>    
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 3;
}
    .child_class {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        border-right-width: 1px;
        border-right-style: solid;
        border-right-color: #5C5C5C;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #child1 {
        width: 33.33;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-position: center center;
        <? set_radius("25px",false,false,true,false,true);?>
        float: left;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    #child2 {
        width: 33.33;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-position: center center;
        background-color: #0CF;
    }

    #child3 {
        <? set_radius("25px",false,true,false,true,false);?>
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-position: center center;
        width: 33.33;
        float: right;
        background-color: #F00;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
          <div class="child_calss" id="child1"></div><div class="child_calss" id="child2"></div><div class="child_calss" id="child3"></div></div>
```

Comment: Maybe instead of dropping its width, you could cover it up with another element that'd grow from the left.

Comment: @Pointy But what if the second div (blue) needs to be adjusted?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your CSS:

```
parent{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then you won't have to bother with matching the `border-radius` on the children, either.

## Edit

I've created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockerest/ahN6A/) to demonstrate:

1. Not needing `border-radius` on the children
2. `overflow: hidden` rounds the children when they overlap
3. Unnecessary `background-` properties on the children are removed
4. Expected behavior at small percentages

### Update

Another note on this:
If you want the CSS/HTML to perform logic for you (not drop the last element out of the bar), you have a clear misunderstanding of what CSS and HTML do.

I've updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockerest/ahN6A/2/) to provide a sort of patch-fix to that issue.  The third child is positioned absolutely at the far right, so that it will always stay in the bar.

### Update

Finally, [here's the bug](https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-unassigned/2011-October/371316.html) in Webkit that doesn't correctly clip the background.  It appears there's nothing you can do right now except possibly something like this:

```
<div class="hasBorder hasBorderRadius">
    <div class="hasBorderRadius hasHiddenOverflow">
        <div class="containsContent">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I do that, the whole child div dissapears when it gets to big (insufficient width).

Comment: Downvoting answers that don't solve your problem is a horrifying response to people trying to help you.  From the FAQ: `Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.`  To respond to your problem: Have you tried to use a `clearfix` on the parent div?  You're floating children without clearing the parent, so it will take a height of `0`, and may account for the children disappearing (not normal) with `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: this seems like the way it was designed to work, if you dynamically adjust the css using inspect element (either width or position in parent)you will see that border radius doesn't round the div,but rounds the inside of the div so the div original shape(square) is kept in-tacked so it still behaves like a square the rounding seems to serve no other purpose then to visually illustrate rounding but not to actually round the element.

Comment: also if you shrink it (reduce width) you'll notice that the rounding is skewing and not resizing(like changing the width of an image without changing it height)

Comment: @codewombat Nope.  That's not how it works.  If you read up on [the border-radius properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius) you'll find that anything that clips to the border clips to the rounded radius.  That's why `overflow: hidden` works with rounded corners.  I've used `border-radius` and `overflow: hidden` to clip content to a rounded corner in the past, so I know it works.  Inspecting elements will usually outline the physical block that the element occupies (i.e., where other elements will not auto place themselves in that area).

Comment: @codewombat I don't know where you're able to do resizing, but if I had to guess, I would assume that another feature of border-radius, [overlapping curves](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corner-overlap) is prohibiting the corners from shaping as intended.

Comment: @rockerest "I don't know where you're able to do resizing" you can dynamically adjust css values in the inspect elements area on the right hand side. are you saying that border-radius on a parent element will clip its children elements with overflow hidden? in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/zv3FV/4/ the child is breaking the out of the parent even though the parent has both a border radius and overflow hidden and the red div child has no radius on it,but the parent still wont clip it...any thoughts on this?

Comment: if you move the red div to the right you will see it move into the overflow area so over flow is working but border radius is just not clipping

Comment: @codewombat What browser/version are you using?  This is what I see [in firefox](http://i.imgur.com/xhOi0.png).  This is the expected/correct result.

Comment: @rockerest im using chrome so i guess this may be a browser issue because in chrome it breaks which lead me to believe it worked that way...strange :P

Comment: @nav_nav what browser are you using

Comment: did some digging and this is a common issue with chrome/safari: http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/11249/chrome-webkit-border-radius-bugs/p1

Comment: Okay, Firstly, @rockerest I'm not responsible for any downvote on this post, as from what I can see, there is no downvote. I appreciate all the help I get from guys on SO, and I use the voting feature appropriately. That said, judging by all the comments and edits to your answer, you clearly WANT to help, so I've up-voted your answer. Now, I have tried using `clear:both;` on the container but the same thing happens (child div dissapears on insufficient width). Your JSFiddle is still not hiding (or "clipping") the corners of the child divs so there still would be a need for a radius. Thanks

Comment: @nav_nav not sure where the downvote came from, I assumed it was you since there was one on all the answers, and you had commented on them all.  As for the problem, this appears to be an issue with the Webkit engine not properly conforming to the W3C CSS3 Recommendation.  Check out the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161826/child-div-overlapping-rounded-with-radius-container-when-at-width-of-2/9162010#comment11532112_9162010) Code Wombat posted.  Is your target audience using mostly Webkit (Safari/Chrome)?  Do you have those statistics?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried giving them a z-index so they have a stack order? also what about an overflow hidden on the parent?

Comment: Overflow hidden does not achieve anything and a z-index also doesn't work.

Comment: ok so i now see whats going on here,border radius is not re-shaping the div from its default rectangle shape, but instead its shaping the inside of the div which means the div still has its original box shape and its children behave a corroding to the rectangle shape and not the border radius which is a type of clipping. check out this:http://jsfiddle.net/zv3FV/2/ use inspect element and dynamically adjust the red div's right (into the negative)to see it be clipped by the original shape of the parent

Comment: the children are not bound by the border radius. this also explanes why overflow doesn't work on the radius because it only works on the original rectangle shape of a div element.

Comment: my comments were not to get it to work, but rather to show you why it wont work